# Do '之后' and '后位' have the same meaning?

Tags: meaning-in-context

According to MDBG and Ichiba, 后位 could mean after/post-something, so what's the difference of '之后' and '后位'?
Which one is correct:
- 葬礼之后
- 葬礼后位

Does 后位 have to follow a noun?

Comment: bkrs：后位 
posterior view; retroposition
postposition (medical term) examples：后位唇
后位子宫
后位子宫子宫托
后位战斗
后位灯
后位肾
后位象
后位阵地
后位限定词， 葬礼之后 makes sense (after the funeral) ，- 葬礼后位 funeral retroposition???

Comment: of course the literal meaning of 后位 understood by everybody is "rear position" so 葬礼后位 might be understood as "the rear of the funeral ceremony (sendoff)"

Comment: users unable to confirm assertions about MDGB,ichacha: neither has any entry for 后位, ichacha has compounds ending in  后位:边后位,额后位, etc. (cf. comment #1), MDGB has much less, in fact not even any compound containing 后位

Comment: Try in MDGB translate page, it will show post-funeral but in the characters  break-down, it didn't show  'post' or 'after', which is why I was confused. I tried in ichiba not ichacha, in ichacha you'd only see it as 'backward displacement'. In ichiba, if you write '后位' you'd get retroposition, but if you write 'noun'+后位, for example '葬礼后位', you'd get 'after the funeral'. That's why I was wondering whether  之后 and 后位 hve the same meaning....

Comment: @Fai91, You can form any combinations with different words, and then look it up in a dictionary and you would get something from there.  It's not a good way because what you formed might not be used at all in practice. Better do it reversely, where you saw/heard something first and then look it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

...之后 is a normal term to express "after...". So,  葬礼之后 is correct in this context.

后位 is short for 后面的位置. It refers to positioning, not timing sequence. It is only used in some particular areas. Someone had given enough examples above.

后位 could also be understood as:

皇后之位 in 宫廷剧 （Chinese royal opera);

Another 后卫： the back (defense position) in sports: soccer, American football, and etc.

Comment: *The back (defense position) in sports: soccer, American football, and etc.*-- that is '后卫' (後衛). Simplified Chinese character merged '後'(back) into  '后'(queen). So 后 in simplified Chinese could mean either 'queen' or 'back'. If you meant ' the defensive zone' , that would be 后防地带 or 后防

Comment: @TangHo oh， yeah, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2):

“后位” is not a common term in daily usage, we barely hear it. As Dan described, it can mean the position of Queen. “之后” and “后面” is commonly mistaken, “之后” is usually used when something happens after something. “后面” is used when something is behind something.